# Creating a macOS notification center app with Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyobjc

I've created a single window Python application using Tkinter.

On macOS there's the notification center which gives quick access to simple widgets, like a calculator or today's calendar events.

I'd like to make my application into a NC widget, but I don't know any Swift or Objective-C.

What would be the easiest way to port my Python application to the NC? Preferably with my Tkinter GUI intact.
I'm hoping PyObjC has something for this.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).